# Uniqueness for antipodal points of maximum distance on closed convex surface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a closed convex surface and let $p,q\in S$ be points such that $d(p,q)=\operatorname{diam}(S)$ where $\operatorname{diam}(S)$ is the diameter of $S$ with respect to the *intrinsic* distance $d$ of $S$.

Does $d(p,q')=\operatorname{diam}(S)$ imply $q=q'$?

Comment: Just a nitpick: the surface itself isn't convex. It's a good question though!

Comment: The surface itself is not a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, I have seen people using this terminology for a surface that bounds a convex set which is what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take two copies of an equilateral triangle $ABC$ and glue them along their boundary.  The resulting surface is homeomorphic to the sphere.  The metric is convex.  Then both $B$ and $C$ are at maximal distance from $A$ so $B$ is not the unique point at maximal distance from $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Make two cuts from a cylinder along two planes that both contain a point $p$ on the surface. If the cuts form the same close to $\pi/2$ angle with the axis you get a surface bounded by a portion of the boundary of the cylinder and two ellipses. There are exactly $2$ points $q$, $q'$ so that $d(p,q) = d(p,q')$ is the diameter of the domain. This would be an oddly shaped salami cut.

Comment: What would the points $q,q'$ in case of the cone? Isn't the (unique) farthest point from the vertex $p$ the center of the disk?

Comment: @Pete: for the cone any point on the base (a circle) can be taken as q provded that the cone is sharp enough

Comment: But the distance from the vertex $p$ to the middle of the disk is greater (surface is closed and we are looking at the intrinsic distance).

Comment: @Pete: i see, the intrinsic distance, the cone does not work indeed.

Comment: Neither does the "salami cut" I think

Comment: @Pete: RIght... But the other answer claims that if you flatten enough the salami you do get a solution.... Now I have to convinve myself of that...not 100% yet

Comment: @Pete: OK, I believe it totally if we take a very flat triangular pyramid and add the symmetric wr to the base ( the other solution basically) except that here I can prove that the diameter is the side of the base.