# Comparison result for diameter of surfaces with intrinsic metric

Tags: geometry

For a surface convex closed surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the intrinsic metric denote by $d_S$ its diameter. Is it true that if $S$ is contained inside $S'$ then $d_S \le d_{S'}$?

Comments:

This is inspired by the question [Uniqueness for antipodal points of maximum distance on closed convex surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344261/uniqueness-for-antipodal-points-of-maximum-distance-on-closed-convex-surface/2344315?noredirect=1#comment4828853_2344315). It would allow to rigorously determine the diameter $d_S$ for some examples related to this previous question.

I believe the answer to be Yes. It should work for any dimension $n\ge 2$ instead of $3$. For $n=2$ it is equivalent to showing that the length of $S$ is $\le $ length of $S'$, a known easily proven fact.

I am not sure if the stronger fact holds: there exists a mapping from $S$ to $S'$ that does not decrease the distances, but this would surely give a quick yes answer.

Perhaps $S'$ need not be convex for this, but definitely $S$ should be.

Attempt: Let $p$, $q$ points on $S$ at distance $d_S$, and $S$ inside $S'$. We may assume ( using a convenient homothety) that $p$, $q$ are themselves on $S'$. I believe now that any path on $S'$ between $p$ and $q$ is not shorter than a corresponding path on $S$ between $p$ and $q$, and that would prove the result, although I do not have a good argument for the last statement.

Any help would be appreciated!